# Is it good practice to have an A tag that just exists for its tooltip?

Tags: html

Is it good practice to have a link that just exists for its tooltip? Like this:

```
<a title="10% off all widgets in September!">$90.00</a>
```

Comment: Just in case of potential browser issues, you might want to include `href='#'`

Comment: Thanks. I usually do `href="javascript:void(0);` instead to avoid any `#` marks in my beautiful URL.

Comment: The question isn't really limited to HTM5 (`title` existed long before this), so I'm taking the liberty to rename and retag this question

Comment: @Yi Jiang I tagged it html5 because if the rules were different for html5 in this situation, I only care about HTML5 rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the tooltip, then `span` should be a better choice, since it carries no semantic information. An anchor would usually indicate a link, so if clicking on that price won't lead anywhere, then an anchor isn't appropriate.

Almost all HTML elements can carry the `title` attribute for accessibility reasons, but you shouldn't depend on it for carrying important information since it is dependent on the user agent (ie. browser) on how best to display this information.